# Get function arguments value by pointer to this function?

Tags: python, pointers, function-pointers

I'd like to get value of function arguments by pointer to that function.

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

def car(cons):
    # local_a = cons.a
    # return local_a
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert car(cons(3, 4)) == 3
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  In your example, what would you expect the values of `a` and `b` to be?  The arguments have no values, because the function hasn't been called.  The arguments will only have values while the function is actually executing.

Comment: What values? Those arguments don't *have* any values at the point where you seem to want them. Function arguments don't work like that.

Comment: Also, argument values are associated with a particular execution of a function, and there can be multiple of those going on at once.

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers

Comment: Your changed example still doesn't work.  If you do `car(cons(3, 4))`, `cons` will completely finish executing before `car` begins, so by the time `car` executes there will be no values for `a` and `b`.  What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Why do you feel you need some external function to "monitor" the variables of `cons` while it is executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the wrong track. Looking at the code in the new version of your question, you're trying to extract the first element of a [Church pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_pairs).

`cons(3, 4)` evaluates to a function that, when passed another function `f`, returns `f(3, 4)`. To extract the `3`, you should pass it a function that takes two arguments and returns its first argument:

```
def car(pair):
    def firstarg(x, y):
        return x
    return pair(firstarg)
```

Then `car(cons(3, 4))` calls `cons(3, 4)(firstarg)`, which calls `firstarg(3, 4)`, which returns `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Signature for the function is easy via the signature function:
    from inspect import signature

```
def someMethod(self, arg1, kwarg1=None):
    pass

sig = signature(someMethod)
```

Now, you can either view its parameters quickly by string it:

```
str(sig)  # returns: '(self, arg1, kwarg1=None)'
```

or you can also get a mapping of attribute names to parameter objects via sig.parameters.

```
params = sig.parameters 
print(params['kwarg1']) # prints: kwarg1=20
```

Additionally, you can call len on sig.parameters to also see the number of arguments this function requires:

```
print(len(params))  # 3
```

Each entry in the params mapping is actually a Parameter object that has further attributes making your life easier. For example, grabbing a parameter and viewing its default value is now easily performed with:

```
kwarg1 = params['kwarg1']
kwarg1.default # returns: None
```

similarly for the rest of the objects contained in parameters.